# Print two or more occurrences using reduce() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

So I have this array of pilots :

```
var pilots = [
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Poe Dameron",
    years: 14,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley",
    years: 30,
  },
  {
    id: 41,
    name: "Tallissan Lintra",
    years: 16,
  },
  {
    id: 99,
    name: "Ello Asty",
    years: 22,
  }
];
```

And I want to print the most experienced pilot. By using reduce() I can print the  most experienced one. But this reduce function will print the last pilot with most experience. In the above array the reduce works perfectly:

```
var mostExpPilot = pilots.reduce(function (oldest, pilot) {
  return (oldest.years || 0) > pilot.years ? oldest : pilot;
}, {});

console.log(mostExpPilot); // Prints { id: 2, name: 'Temmin \'Snap\' Wexley', years: 30 }
```

If we have 2 or more pilots with the same experience and I want to print both occurrences. For example we have the below array where there are two pilots with the same years of experience. The reduce function that is implemented it prints only the last pilot.

```
var pilots = [
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "Poe Dameron",
      years: 14,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley",
      years: 30,
    },
    {
      id: 41,
      name: "Tallissan Lintra",
      years: 30,
    },
    {
      id: 99,
      name: "Ello Asty",
      years: 22,
    }
  ];



//find the most experienced pilot 
var mostExpPilot = pilots.reduce(function (oldest, pilot) {
    return (oldest.years || 0) > pilot.years ? oldest : pilot;
  }, {});

console.log(mostExpPilot); // prints { id: 41, name: 'Tallissan Lintra', years: 30 }
```

Can I do it with reduce() ? If yes, could you please let me know? If no, how can I do that? Thanks.**

Comment: use "filterAll" function instead of "reduce" function.

Comment: You can do that with reduce as long as you change the return type to an array instead of an object. Besides, it would make far more sense to first **group** the results by age, then **sort** them by year and return the desired instance. You are actually using reduce to **sort** the items.

Comment: Why does it have to be done with `reduce`?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I am just asking. I saw the example and thought about this problem.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: It's probably faster doing it with `reduce` than in another way, since `reduce` does it in a single pass; the downside is that it is somewhat less readable than finding maximum and then using filter, or grouping then finding maximum, or sorting then taking the top equal items.

Comment: @Amadan ohh I see. this looks fancy. I was just thinking at the first moment but know I see that it may have some advantages. :O

Comment: @Amadan I agree reduce does it in one pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mostExpPilot = pilots.reduce(function (oldest, pilot) {
    return oldest[0].years < pilot.years ? [pilot] : (oldest[0].years == pilot.years ? [...oldest, pilot] : oldest);
  }, [pilots[0]]);

console.log(mostExpPilot);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, though it's not very common idiom:

```
const oldestPilots = pilots => pilots.reduce((oldest, pilot) => {
  if (!oldest.length || oldest[0].years < pilot.years) return [pilot];
  if (oldest[0].years == pilot.years) return [...oldest, pilot];
  return oldest;
}, [])
```

Comment: This looks alright but I don't know why it does not print anything.

Comment: It defines a function. Do `console.log(oldestPilots(pilots))` to print something.

Comment: yea there was an error with the previous variables I had created. Just did that. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

> If we have 2 or more pilots with the same experience and I want to print both occurrences.

To do that, you'll need to return an array. If you're going to return an array *sometimes*, it's best to return an array *always* (even if it will have only one entry in it).

You'd do it by returning an array with just the current pilot if that pilot has more experience than the previously-known pilot, adding the current pilot to the array if they have the same experience, or keeping the previously-known pilot otherwise:

```js
var pilots = [
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "Poe Dameron",
      years: 14,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley",
      years: 30,
    },
    {
      id: 41,
      name: "Tallissan Lintra",
      years: 30,
    },
    {
      id: 99,
      name: "Ello Asty",
      years: 22,
    }
];

// Find the most experienced pilots
var mostExpPilot = pilots.reduce(function(most, pilot) {
    var mostYears = most[0] ? most[0].years : -1;
    if (mostYears < pilot.years) {
        return [pilot];
    }
    if (mostYears === pilot.years) {
        most.push(pilot);
    }
    return most;
}, []);

console.log(mostExpPilot);
```

Comment: If you see `null` at the end of `reduce`, hit refresh. `null` would be a bug if the pilots array were empty. (A bug in that the result wouldn't always be an array.)

Comment: Crowder Thanks. Got it!

Comment: That's a bit faster than mine, due to nice `push`. Watch out for people with negative ages. :P

Comment: @Amadan - Is it? I guess because of the spread, which uses an iterator. Yours is more FP-like, though, which fits nicely with `reduce`. :-)

Comment: @Amadan - Yeah, I kinda meant both. (Pity the OP decided to unaccept yours and accept one that's nearly identical, just harder to read...)

Answer (score 1):

The following gets it all down to two lines but takes more passes than reduce (which takes just one).  Nevertheless if the sample size will always be small the readability may be worth it:

```
const mostYearsExperience = Math.max.apply({}, pilots.map(p => p.years));
const mostExperiencedPilots = pilots.filter(p => p.years === mostYearsExperience);
```